# Ubuntu 17.10 no sound on cherry trail laptop

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio

Is it possible to have sound muted by default in ubuntu 17.10?

I have a cherry trail laptop with intel x5-z8350 processor. More info about my laptop, as you can see there are audio devices listed and recognized:

```
aplay -l
**** Lista PLAYBACK urządzeń ****
karta 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], urządzenie 0: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], urządzenie 1: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], urządzenie 2: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: bytcrrt5651 [bytcr-rt5651], urządzenie 0: 1 []
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: bytcrrt5651 [bytcr-rt5651], urządzenie 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
kamila@Kiano:~$ 

 inxi -F
System:    Host: Kiano Kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.26.1 Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
Machine:   Device: laptop System: KIANO product: KIANO SlimNote 14.1 serial: N/A
           Mobo: AMI model: Cherry Trail CR serial: N/A
           UEFI: N/A v: WH-BI-14-Y116CR510-CC54B-063-A date: 08/16/2017
CPU:       Quad core Intel Atom x5-Z8350 (-MCP-) cache: 1024 KB
           clock speeds: max: 1920 MHz 1: 1440 MHz 2: 1440 MHz 3: 1440 MHz
           4: 1440 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers
           Display Server: wayland (X.Org 1.19.5 ) driver: i915
           Resolution: 1366x768@59.80hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (Cherrytrail)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 17.2.2
Audio:     Card-1 Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio driver: HdmiLpeAudio
           Card-2 bytcr-rt5651 driver: bytcr-rt5651
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-16-generic
Network:   Card: Failed to Detect Network Card!
Drives:    HDD Total Size: NA (-)
           ID-1: /dev/mmcblk0 model: N/A size: 31.3GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 29G used: 9.1G (34%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/mmcblk0p2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 209 Uptime: 10 min Memory: 809.1/3872.9MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.37
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The above solution Will solve the problem sound but only headphones work..
Use the kernel 4.19 It supports the device well speakers will work
Disable/ enable the sound card whenever you change the port 
Use alsamixer to look for left and right controls (HPO L...)

Answer (score 0):

i have a very similar setup with bytcr-rt5651 and ubuntu 17.10 this fixed mine:

1. in etc/modprobe.d create file blacklist_hdmi.conf with contents:

blacklist snd_hdmi_lpe_audio

2. download and run this linixium sh script:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99O3A0dDe67VUNMV2xfVjJKeVk/edit

3. in /usr/share/alsa/ucm/ create a bytcr-rt5651 folder with contents:

asound.state

bytcr-rt5651.conf

HiFi.conf

4. sudo alsa force-reload
5. rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
6. pulseaudio -k
7. reboot
8. open pavucontrol and set configuration profile to HiFi and change output from headphones to speakers.